# Can the MahlKoenig EK43 be calibrated coarser?

Tags: grinder

We just got in our new EK43; When we dial in to highest grind size (11 on our dial), it is much finer than what I would normally use for French Press, or even for Chemex or automatic drip.

Here are some pictures of grounds around a penny, to compare size.

Setting 1:
[image]

Setting 6:
[image]

Setting 11:

[image]

Comment: You mean coarser than the standard settings? So on all settings it will be coarser as compared to factory calibration?

Comment: Correct. It’s just out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can adjust the calibration of grind size of the EK43.

Have the grinder plugged in and ready. Turn the adjustment knob all the way to the right. Losen the two screws on the sides of the knob slightly (turn the hexagon shaped screwdriver once). The screws are on the sides of the knob, fixing the big adjustment screw in the middle of the knob. Once they are losend you can use a flat head screwdriver or a coin to turn the screw in the middle of the know. Keep the knob totally turned to the right, to the smallest grind size setting.

So now normally you would turn it slowly to the right while your grinder is turned on until you hear a slight rattling sound. This sound occurs when the burrs are touching. Once you hear the sound, immediately turn the screw back by about ten degrees until the sound stops and the burrs aren't touching anymore. That is the standard calibration and the only one viable for espresso.

In your case you want to turn the screw further counter clockwise, so the burrs are further apart until you get the desired grind size. The maximum grind size will be coarser as well as the minimum. That also means that the grinder will not grind fine enough for espresso anymore.

I don't know if this is recommendable to do, I don't think anything can break. But I will also not guarantee it. To be sure write a mail to Mahlkönig. Also I think there are instructions in the grinder manual on how to calibrate it (to the standard espresso setting).